# Getting out of a while loop using input

Tags: python, input, while-loop

i am preparing a function to user to guess a random number generated by computer.

The output should be the number of guesses, and if the guess is correct, lower or higher than the generated number.

In the end the, the user should be asked if he wants to play again or not.

Everything is working excepts this last part, because i can't break the loop to stop the game.

Here's my code:

```
#random number guessing game

import random

def generate_random (min,max):
    return random.randint (min,max)

#generate_random (1,100)

star_range=1
end_range=100

#targetnumber=generate_random(start_range,end_range)
#print (targetnumber)

def main():
    targetnumber=generate_random(star_range,end_range)
    number_of_guesses =0 #guarda o numero de tentativas do jogador
    
    print ("Guess a number between 0 e 100.\n")
    
    while True:
        number_of_guesses +=1
        guess = int(input("Guess #" + str(number_of_guesses) + ": "))
        
        if guess > targetnumber:
            print("\t Too High, try again.")
        elif guess < targetnumber:
            print ("\t Too low, try aain")
        else:
            print ("\t Correct")
            print ("\t Congratulations. you got it in",number_of_guesses,"guesses.")
            
            break
        
    playagain=input("\n whould you like to play again? (y/n): ").lower()
    while playagain != "y" or playagain != "n":
        print ("Please print y to continue or n to exit")
        playagain=input("\n whould you like to play again? (y/n): ").lower()
            
   
        if playagain == "y":
            continue
        else:
            break
```

My final output is always this one:

whould you like to play again? (y/n): n
Please print y to continue or n to exit

whould you like to play again? (y/n):

Can you please help me, letting me know what i am doing wrong?

Thank you very much

Comment: `playagain` can never be both "y" and "n" at the same time: `playagain != "y" or playagain != "n"` is always True. Use `and` instead of `or`.

Answer (score 0):

The condition evaluation is always True, hence you get into the loop again.

```
while playagain not in ['y', 'n']:
   ...
```

would satisfy your input check

Also, your continue/break condition is only evaluated if the while loop condition is met (i.e., the input was not correct)

Comment: Hello Simon,

thank you very much for your answer.

I used

 while playagain not in ['y', 'n']:

and it worked just fine, but i'm not getting to the while loop to continue playing. It just stop.

 playagain=input("\n whould you like to play again? (y/n): ").lower()
    while playagain not in ["y","n"]:
        print ("Please print y to continue or n to exit")
        playagain=input("\n whould you like to play again? (y/n): ").lower()
        
            
    while True:
       if playagain == "n":
           break
      else:
          continue

What do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are continuing the second "while" loop and not moving back to your "game" code when you check the equality of the string "y" as the input, thus the question gets asked again. Instead, you should try refactoring the loops so that your game loop is nested inside the retry loop.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've changed the while loop of the y and n answer, because i have to check these 2 conditions, but i am not solving the loop to start the game again.

Do you have any suggestion?